# jquery timer get old value every time

Tags: jquery, timer

I'm using http://code.cyntaxtech.com/plugins/jquery-timer library (jquery.timer.js).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var previous_id=$("#rows td").first().text();

    $('#rows').timer({
        delay: 5000,
        repeat: true,
        url: "test.php?id="+previous_id,
        callback: function() {
            // insert a new <td> element with value that must be a 'previous_id' in next timer fire
        }
    });
});
```

Every time I receive old previous_id value :( I've read some articles and understand that I must determine the variable previous_id in function (timer). But how can I do it in above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the variable `` ` after inserting the new ``td`

```
callback: function() {
            // insert a new <td> element with value that must be a 'previous_id' in next timer fire
            previous_id=$("#rows td").first().text();
        }
```